# chrome extension - creating new popup window results in a blank one until I move it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Someone probably encountered this problem.

So, I'm creating a new popup window like this:

```
const options = {
    type: "popup",
    url: "login_popup.html",
    width: 440,
    height: 490,
    left: (screen.width / 2) - (440 / 2),
    top: (screen.height / 2) - (490 / 2)
}

chrome.windows.create(options)
```

There's also another window that I create in the same manner but is a bit different by itself. Both ***time to time*** (not always!) remain blank (full white) until I move the window. What is the problem?

Comment: If your OS is Windows then it's a bug in Chrome, https://crbug.com/1137982. It'd be helpful if you click the star and add a comment there describing details of your OS setup.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I think I didn't encounter this before - not with my own extensions nor with any other. Is it a recent update that causes this bug to appear? Is there any sort of workaround?

Comment: Yes, it's a recent thing. You can start chrome with `--disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion` command line or disable `chrome://flags/#calculate-native-win-occlusion` in chrome://flags

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, seems not to be an option if the extension will be put to the store. Do you think they will be able to solve this bug quite fast (month-two at least)?

Comment: One-two years and I would call it fast. Lots of extensions-related bugs take 5 years and more.

Comment: @wOxxOm god damn! Now I'm not sure if I can find a workaround for production? Can you tell me if there is any way to open a popup (tell me anything) without this bug? If not - what could I do else? This seems to be a solid flaw.

Comment: Try resizing the window by one pixel right after creating it.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the tip. That didn't help, however there was some strange behavior right now (with/without fix attempt it was the same). So I'm opening the popup on extension load as well as on context menu item click. I was refreshing the extension for a ton of times and it was opening a popup without the problem. However, after I close it and try to use the context menu - it was giving me blank window 9/10 times. What's the most annoying thing - right before I went to tell you this - it was opening the popup from context menu without a problem for 10/10 of attempts. Da hell is this?!

Comment: @wOxxOm ok, seems that I found the solution. And yes, it's something about resizing the window after you create it, but only after the window is at "complete" state (it's first tab). I also found out that changing the position is a bit better than resizing the window - because resizing causes a noticeable effect, while moving the window by 1 pixel does not. I'll post my solution soon in the answer, gonna test it a little bit more.

Comment: @wOxxOm check my answer and let me know if that works.

Comment: To simplify the code you can probably replace waitForCompleteState with a listener for `load` or `DOMContentLoaded` event in the script that runs inside the popup.

Comment: @wOxxOm eg instead of waiting for complete state just send `chrome.runtime` message to the background script on "load" event and apply the fix afterwards?

Comment: You can call `chrome` API inside that popup so you can just move the resizing code there.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah, right, my head is overwhelmed after attempting to fix this, totally forgot about that. Though, only applies to `chrome://` urls, right?

Comment: @wOxxOm yup, sorry, I meant `chrome-extension://` urls. What I tried to say is that if you open a popup with an external url, this should be a whole another story...

Answer (score 1):

Moving it or changing its size would be the solution.
I had the same problem and solved it this way.
I realize it's not a good solution, but it can be used to simplify the code.

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(wind) {
    setTimeout(() => { chrome.windows.update(wind.id, { top: 7 }); }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for anyone out there struggling with this problem, I'm posting a solution which worked out for me. Keep in mind that without waiting for complete state the whole thing will fail (maybe in certain cases, I don't know, but for me it's crucial).

```
async function openLoginPopup(){

    const options = {
        type: "popup",
        url: "login_popup.html",
        width: 440,
        height: 490,
        left: (screen.width / 2) - (440 / 2),
        top: (screen.height / 2) - (490 / 2)
    }

    const chromeWindow = await chrome_windows_create(options)
    await applyTemporaryWindowFix(chromeWindow)

    /* Do something if needed */

}

async function applyTemporaryWindowFix(chromeWindow){

    const options = {
        left: (screen.width / 2) - (440 / 2) - 1,
    }

    await waitForCompleteState(chromeWindow.tabs[0].id)
    await chrome_windows_update(chromeWindow.id, options)

}

async function waitForCompleteState(tabId) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        loop()

        async function loop() {
        
            const { status } = await chrome_tabs_get(tabId)

            if (status == "complete")
                return resolve()

            setTimeout(loop, 100)

        }

    })
}

function chrome_windows_create(options){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.windows.create(options, resolve)
    })
}

function chrome_windows_update(chromeWindowId, options){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.windows.update(chromeWindowId, options, resolve)
    })
}

function chrome_tabs_get(tabId){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.tabs.get(tabId, resolve)
    })
}
```

You can also change the `width/height` instead of `left/top` position, but for me changing the position is a bit better. It doesn't produce a semi-noticeable effect, so basically looks like nothing extra happened.

Test well. This bug is random.

Also a note from [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom):

> To simplify the code you can probably replace waitForCompleteState
> with a listener for load or DOMContentLoaded event in the script that
> runs inside the popup. You can call chrome API inside that popup so you can
> just move the resizing code there.